# Will removing a TableSection also remove all Tapped event links?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code that I use to remove the Tapped events from a section

```
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        foreach (var section in tableView.Root)
        {
            foreach (var cell in section)
            {
                cell.Tapped -= openCategoriesPage;
            }
        }
    }
```

Would it be the same if I just did this:

```
    tableView.Root.RemoveAt(1);
```

I want to be sure that the Tapped event is 100% removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not the same - as `tableView.Root.RemoveAt(1)` will only disconnect the section from table - not the event handlers.

The simplest way to test this would be to add section back in `TableView` after removing it. And a tap on a cell should still trigger `openCategoriesPage`. i.e.

```
 //get reference to section
 var section = tableView.Root.First();
 //remove section from tableview
 tableView.Root.RemoveAt(1);
 //now add section back to tableview
 tableView.Root.Add(section); 
 // taps on cell should still trigger the handler
```